# Windows phone 8 and Azure AD / ACS

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, azure-active-directory, accesscontrolservice

I am developing a WP8 app, which requires authentication in order to get a token to call the web api backend. I don't want to create my own account management mechanism, because it seems silly in our day and age to implement my own account repository.

I am using Azure anyway, so I thought to leverage it for the user management and authentication/authorization. What better place to manage users than Active Directory. If I also use ACS, I can get both "native" accounts and using other providers (Facebook, Microsoft Accounts, etc.) right out of the box.

So I have been searching for DAYS and I can't find even one tutorial or example or even someone talking about a flow that includes WP8, Azure AD/ACS and Web API.

I can only find tutorials on authenticating with Mobile Services and I don't want to use that, as it seems much to simple for what I need.

Is this use case even supported currently? Can one authenticate users of a WP8 app using Azure AD and then receive a token for authorization with a Web API hosted in a VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vittorio has just blogged about this:

[A Sample Windows Phone 8 App Getting Tokens from Windows Azure AD and ADFS](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/16/A-SAMPLE-WINDOWS-PHONE-8-APP-GETTING-TOKENS-FROM-WINDOWS-AZURE-AD-AND-ADFS/).

The article also has a link to his earlier one - [Fun With Windows Azure AD: Calling REST Services from a Windows Phone 8 App](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/04/29/fun-with-windows-azure-ad-calling-rest-services-from-a-windows-phone-8-app/) (which may have been one you found?).

Comment: Yes! This was what I was looking for. Seems like this type of flow is still a work-in-progress :) Thank you!